# HttpError with custom payload in WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to return custom payload with non 200 return code using ASP.NET WebApi. Basically I want to have

```
{"status":{"code":"40001", "message": "Field XXX can not be empty"}}
```

and

```
<status><code>40001</code><message>Field XXX can not be empty</message></status>
```

I'm doing it using `HttpError` class, by adding `Dictionary` with rerquired payload. It works perfectly for JSON, but fails for XML, and as I understand it boils down to `XmlSerializer` and `HttpError` not playing nicely.

Here is a short code snippet to reproduce exactly same error:

```
var error = new HttpError();
var status = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"code", "40001"},
    {"text", "Field XXX can not be empty"}
};
error.Add("status", status);
var ser = new XmlSerializer(error.GetType());
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
ser.Serialize(strWriter, error);
```

In this case I'm getting `Xml type 'xdt:untypedAtomic' does not support a conversion from Clr type 'KeyValuePair 2' to Clr type 'String'`

Next step is to realize that `KeyValuePair` is not serializeable, and create separate class:

```
[XmlType(TypeName="Status")]
public class ResponseStatus
{
  public ResponseStatus(){}
  public String Code 
  { get; set; }

  public String Text
  { get; set; }
}
```

which by itself serializes just fine, but throws pretty same exception if used inside HttpError:
`Xml type 'List of xdt:untypedAtomic' does not support a conversion from Clr type 'ResponseStatus' to Clr type 'String'.`

I don't believe nobody did this before, so I wonder what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way;

```
HttpError err = new HttpError();
err["code"] = "40001";
err["text"] = "Field XXX can not be empty";
```

then return it via HttpResponseMessage at the controller level ie

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.--, err);
```

For you to return {"status":{"code":"40001", "message": "Field XXX can not be empty"}}, you might have to create a complex type ie

```
public class ResponseStatus
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
     public string code { get; set; }
     public string message { get; set; }
}
```

and then instantiate the two classes from say your controller ie

```
Status st = new Status();
st.code = "40001";
st.message = "Field XXX can not be empty";

ResponseStatus responsStatus = new ResponseStatus();
responsStatus.status = st;
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responsStatus);
```

For more control over your output consider decorating your classes with   [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and  [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the properties. from these namespaces System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and using System.Runtime.Serialization ie

```
[DataContract]
class Status
{
      [DataMember(Name = "code")]
      public string code { get; set; }
      [DataMember(Name = "message")]
      public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I modified initial question. Serializing strings works, but I need those keys to be wrapped inside "status" field. In this case serialization fails